# Is it ok that installing package gives a warning: package ‘...’ was built under R version 3.3.2?

Tags: r, installation, dplyr

I have a problem with installing dplyr in RStudio. When I try to install the package, it says :

```
install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Kalia LOFITOU/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/dplyr_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2407895 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Kalia LOFITOU\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWKOWYM\downloaded_packages
> library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.3.2
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have successfully installed `dplyr`. Check `library(dplyr)` .That isn't an error message.

Comment: Retitled. Untagged [tag:rstudio]; RStudio is only an IDE. You are installing dplyr in R, not RStudio.

Comment: @RonakShah: yes, but it's a reasonable question, so no reason for whoever downvoted. Installing a newer package under even a slightly older version of R can cause lots of warnings.

Comment: @smci What gives you an idea that I have down voted this question?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, zx8754: installing a package and creating a package are different things and will be indexed under different phrases, even if the underlying warning is the same.

Comment: @smci I voted this "as no longer reproducible". I didn't mark it as a dupe

Comment: @DavidArenburg: it's entirely reproducible (just uninstall and reinstall the package). I hit it several times a week.

Comment: @smci OP says that they have a problem installing dplyr while there is no problem and the package was installed. I can't think of any better reason to close.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: the warnings make it hard to figure whether an install succeeded or failed. R has a generic issue with confusing, badly-worded, superfluous or missing warnings, or incorrect severity. There are tons of other examples. I personally found three yesterday using other packages. I'm a 5-year user of R and this stuff still inconveniences me and many others daily. In this case, the warnings give the appearance that there is a problem. That in itself is a problem. This should never have been closed.

Comment: @smci Well, I disagree. I think this warning is very informative and there is nothing overcomplicated about it. Other than that, the first step OP should have done is to test it using `library(dplyr)` or simply Google it. Other than that we both have the right to disagree. It is my right to close this as it is your right to try to reopen it.

Comment: A successful install should result in an affirmative message: "package ‘dplyr’ successfully installed" (not just "unpacked", which can still result in a fail in most languages/installers). The severity of this message is arguably "Info" not "Warning", especially since it's misleading to many users. Our votes are canceling each other out, this is not productive.

Comment: Thank you very much for you responses! Indeed, dplyr is working perfectly :) Rstudio is new for me so i'm trying to catch up. Have a nice day